# count files watched by grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I have got a new Angular + Node project from my client, which i set it up on my local. The application is running fine. But the one problem is the CPU is taking 100% when I run the `grunt` command and my system hangs.But on my client machine with same configuration, everything seems to running fine.

After looking into many threads I found that this kind of issue occurs when grunt is watching too many files. I also used the `grunt watch --verbose` to see the files I am watching. Actually I fell like we are watching a lot of unnecessary files like angluar and jquery library files.

Is there any way/plugin to get the exact count how many files I am watching via the grunt command?

Answer (score 2):

If it works fine on a machine, which is the same configuration/environment, but has more horsepower, then I think you are correct to assume you are watching too many files.

If you haven't already, you should run grunt watch on a config that only watches a few files to further support the path that you are simply watching too many files.

Finally, you should only ever be watching files that need to be watched, or in other words are going to actually be changing during development. Third party libraries and the like should absolutely not be included in that set!

My recommendation to you is to only watch the files you need to watch, and you can specify exactly the files you need to watch or use glob patterns with some degree of specificity. I'll also point out that you can use the negation operator `!` with glob.

If after following my recommendation, you are still having the same trouble, you have three options as I see it:

1. Create more specific watch tasks, and run only one or two of them at a time.
2. Upgrade your hardware
3. Don't use watch at all, and just trigger a task manually from the command line.

**EDIT:**
Adding in answer from comments below since it directly addresses the question asked.

To count the files watched by grunt, use the linux find command and pipe it to `wc -l`. So if you are operating in your project root and want to count the number of files with the .js extension that live in the src directory and its subdirectories, then this would look something like `find . -name "src/*.js" | wc -l`. What we are doing here is finding all the files that match your criteria and then getting a count of the number of files by using the wc command with the -l to count newlines in the stdout.

Comment: I ran `grunt watch --verbose` and copy all the watched file names from my terminal and pasted in a notepad++ file , I can see its watching around 1152 files. Is it sufficient to make CPU usage 100%?

Comment: There are variables, like the power of your CPU, that prevent me from answering that with certainty. In short though, yes it is possible. That is a lot of files. I would be more precise with the files that you are watching. Also, you should make sure you are running the latest versions of both grunt and grunt-contrib-watch, as there have been numerous performance improvements in the history of grunt-contrib-watch.

Comment: Also, even though it seems you do have a rough count of the files, to answer the question of how to count the files watched by grunt, use the linux find command and pipe it to `wc -l`. So if you are operating in your project root and want to count the number of files with the .js extension that live in the src directory and its subdirectories, then this would look something like `find .  -name "src/*.js" | wc -l`. What we are doing here is finding all the files that match your criteria and then getting a count of the number of files by using the `wc` command with the `-l` to count newlines.